# Import json file to mock data for my tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I try to mock data in my jasmine tests.

In a component spec I use:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  const user: User = require('../../mocks/user.json');
```

I a service stub that I put inside */src/mocks/services/service.stub.ts*

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export const MyServiceStub =  {
  users: require('../../mocks/users.json'),

  getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.users);
  }
};
```

With this *npm run test* works but the app doesn't compile because of

> ERROR in src/app/mocks/services/UserServiceStub.ts(4,15): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

I've tried modifying *tsconfig.json* with

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true  
  }
```

And import mocks json with:

```
import * as users from '../../mocks/users.json';
```

This destroyed all my imports like momentJS (import * as moment from 'moment')

I read I could just add

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

But this didn't help...

What's the right way to import a json file in my tests?

EDIT: I forgot to say that *require* works in my spec files, it just fails when I use it in */src/mocks/services/MyService.stub.ts*

I modified the stubbed service to be a class and changed the provider to use *useClass* instead of *useValue* but this didn't help.

Comment: I think you are doing wrong way. you need to get data by using mock service

Comment: I could hardcode the data in the service but I want to stay DRY

Comment: I edited the question, require works in .spec.ts but not in the stub

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have something like:

```
export const USER_OBJECTS: User[] = [
    {
        'firstName': 'Ana',
        'lastName': '..',
        'fullName': '..',
        'userName': '..',
        'email': '...'
    } as User,
    {
        'firstName': 'Lisa',
        'lastName': '..',
        'fullName': '..',
        'userName': '...',
        'email': '...'
    } as User
];
```

In your `mocks/users.json.ts` and import it into your stubs file like:

```
import {USERS_OBJECTS} from '../mocks/users.json.ts';
```

Then your stub service would look like:

```
export const MyServiceStub =  {
  users: require('../../mocks/users.json'),

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return of(USER_OBJECTS);
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, that solves my problem so I accept the answer. I was just hoping I could just use json files... Thanks (I'll have to exclude these from the build though)